# Compare two multidimensional arrays with different number of elements

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have two multidimensional arrays with different number of elements:

```
$complete = array(array("24","G:\TVShows\24"),array("Lost","G:\TVShows\Lost"),array("Game of Thrones","G:\TVShows\Game of Thrones"));
$subset = array(array("24","G:\TVShows\24","English"));
```

The first one ($complete) is the complete list of my tv shows on disk (name of the show, path to files). The second one ($subset) come from my database and include the spoken language as a third column / element.

I would like to return the shows that I have on disk but that do not appear in databse. How can I compare those to array with different number of elements?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you use the name (or better, an ID) as the array keys, you can use standard array functions to get the keys, compare them, etc. So I would build the arrays differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since its a multi leveled array, you could use and combine `array_map()` and `serialize()/unserialize()`. Consider this example:

```
$complete = array(
    array("24","G:\TVShows\24"),
    array("Lost","G:\TVShows\Lost"),
    array("Game of Thrones","G:\TVShows\Game of Thrones"),
    array("The Walking Dead","G:\TVShows\The Walking Dead"),
    array("Breaking Bad","G:\TVShows\Breaking Bad"),
    array("Heroes","G:\TVShows\Heroes"),
);

$subset = array(
    array("24","G:\TVShows\24","English"),
    array("The Walking Dead","G:\TVShows\The Walking Dead","English"),
    array("Heroes","G:\TVShows\Heroes","English"),
);

$shows_not_in_db = array();
// properly format the subsets for comparison on complete
foreach($subset as $key_s => $value_s) {
    array_pop($value_s); // remove the last element "English"
    $subset[$key_s] = serialize($value_s);
}

// serialize each complete arrays
$complete = array_map('serialize', $complete);
$shows_not_in_db = array_map('unserialize', array_diff($complete, $subset)); // array diff them, then unserialize

print_r($shows_not_in_db);
```

[**Sample Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/dAI5pj)

> Edit: For case insensitive comparisons, you may use this alternative:

```
$shows_not_in_db = array_map('unserialize', array_udiff($complete, $subset, 'strcasecmp'));

// sample: The walking dead - The Walking Dead
```